# Error while using svn2git for SVN to GIT migration

Tags: git, version-control, svn2git

I am getting below error when I tried to use svn2git command to import svn files

*Running command: git svn init --prefix=svn/ --no-metadata --trunk=trunk --tags=tags --branches=branches https://svnserver.com/abc/svn/projectname
Running command: git svn fetch
Invalid filesystem revision number: svn: E160006: Invalid revision number '-1' a
t /mingw64/share/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 150.
command failed:
git svn fetch*

I got the same error when I tried to check out using tortoise SVN client. Then I installed the client same as the SVN server version and the issue got resolved.

But when using **svn2git**, same error occurs? Is there any version compatibility issue? I am using SVN 1.7.9 and svn2git 2.3.2.

Comment: It seems you also  install 64 bit git bash. Please uninstall it and install 32 bit git instead.

Comment: Is it fine to install 32 bit on 64 bit OS?

Comment: Yes, it's ok to install 32 bit git on 64 bit OS.

Comment: Still no luck :( .

Comment: C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\abc\GITLAB>svn2git https://svnserver.com/abc/svn/projectname

Invalid filesystem revision number: svn: E160006: Invalid revision number '-1' at /mingw32/share/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 150.

command failed:
git svn fetch

Answer (score 0):

You are using an `svn2git` tool that uses `git-svn` under the hood.

For a one-time migration `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or parts of repositories. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want from your current SVN layout, including any complex histories that might exist and including producing several Git repos out of one SVN repo or combining different SVN repos into one Git repo cleanly.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` (or the svn2git you used) is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)